# Why the wp_localize_script() does not work correct in my case? ( /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request) )

Tags: ajax, wp-localize-script

Hi I use the next environment for adding the script and style to my WordPress theme:

```
function theme_scripts() {


// Load the html5 IE.
wp_enqueue_script('iceers-html5', ' 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js', array(), '');
wp_script_add_data('iceers-html5', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');


wp_enqueue_style(
    'styles',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main.min.css'
);
wp_enqueue_style(
    'style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
);


$localize_arr = array(
    'home_url' => home_url(),
    'home_path' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri(),
    'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('view-nonce')
);

wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);

wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'wp_helper', $localize_arr );


 }

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

But when I try to create ajax request. There is error in console: POST domain.test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request) Here is the chunk of code where I try to try do the ajax request:

```
      $.ajax({
            url: wp_helper.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $wrapper.removeClass('processing');
                if (data) {
                    $('#design-row').append(data);
                    wp_helper.current_page++;
                    console.log(wp_helper.current_page);
                    console.log(wp_helper.max_page);
                    if (wp_helper.current_page == wp_helper.max_page) {
                        $container.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
          });
```

I can not solve it myself. For my opinion it should work but it does not, and I tried but can not find the error. Please help me to figure out in this situation.

Comment: The cause of a 400 error in admin-ajax.php is _always_ the same. Always. Have you checked the answers for any similar questions? This error happens when the `action` parameter is missing from the request or an equivalent `wp_ajax_${action}` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_${action}` hasn't been registered. You haven't included any code for how your request is handled, or what `data` is so it's not possible to say which is the problem.

Comment: Also, your AJAX request is being sent to admin-ajax.php, which means that `wp_helper.ajax_url` is obviously correct, so `wp_localize_script()` can't be the problem since that must be working.

Comment: @JacobPeattie You are right, thanks and sorry for nubby question. I really get it the 404 ajax error in WP is the error of the function connection.  The reason: my family had to relocate two time at one week and it broken my mind.